# What are the browser and resolution stats for SO users?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

Google Analytics (and some log parsers) will give you breakdowns on usage of different browsers, different versions of those browsers and screen resolutions.

I'm just curious to know what SO users user. Any chance we could get some stats on that? You may view this as commercial information, in which case I understand (as i'ts relevant to marketing/advertising).

I'm also curious to know the # of users who read and/or post from mobile devices and if so which ones.

**UPDATE: Please refrain from personal anecdotes ("I use...").** I'm interested in actual usage, not personal stories. Thankyou.

Comment: This was asked before but resulted in a somewhat sad outcome, I'll try to find it.

Comment: How do you measure screen resolution when you have multiple monitors?

Comment: It was asked before and died a deleted death. Had some browsers and then when it started to tip with including systems of those browsers, vompf! Gone.

Comment: @John, resolution of each individual monitor. @random, that would explain why I can't find it but it didn't have any helpful information anyways (maybe the setup of 20 different users at best)

Comment: Let's see how fast this one gets deleted.

Comment: Why would this get deleted?

Comment: Who knows, but as Barack said, the other question like this died quick.

Comment: Maybe the analytics could be included in the data dump. After all, if SOFU is YOU, doesn't that include what you view the site in?

Comment: So, you edit it 4 hours after you ask the question and then downvote everyone who answered your pre-edited version of the question?

Comment: Well I thought it was clear that I was after stats not anecdotes. Why else mention Google Analytics? Apparently not so I clarified it.

Comment: There are two parts to your question that ask for specific information: "I'm just curious to know what SO users use" and "I'm also curious to know the # of users who read and/or post from mobile devices", and it's flagged for 'discussion'. We were just discussing.

Comment: It was flagged for discussion because it has to be one of support, feature-request, bug or discussion and it doesn't fit the others. FYI it's not me downvoting these answers. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough but the intent was never to turn this into a "I use..." thread. If you want to start one, be my guest. My suggestion to those who have mistakenly posted that that it's probably best just to delete their answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/) (Analytics data from June 1st – August 19th):

**Browser:**

```
    Firefox             50.53%
    Internet Explorer   29.12%
      IE8                8.44% (29% of IE)
      IE7               13.10% (45% of IE)
      IE6                6.99% (24% of IE)
    Chrome               9.04%
    Safari               7.33%
    Opera                2.44%
    Mozilla              1.15%
    Konqueror            0.10%
```

**Screen Size:**

```
    1280×1024           24.03%
    1680×1050           14.52%
    1280×800            14.32%
    1024×768            12.32%
    1440×900            11.57%
    1920×1200            8.40%
    1600×1200            3.24%
    1152×864             1.68%
    1920×1080            1.32%
    1400×1050            1.28%
```

Comment: People still use Firefox?

Comment: @random: They must be Linux users.

Comment: I'd seen this too but I guess someone had to be first to post it. :)

Comment: Shouldn't there by a listing for Unknown browsers? What about people who block google analytics? I'm guessing Firefox usage is under-counted; people block google analytics using NoScript, even when they enable the rest of the site. Me, I just use /etc/hosts.

Comment: I would be surprised that those disable Javascript, block analytics, use hosts files to block certain sites, etc would account for, at most, 2% of the population for even technical sites like SO.

Comment: Adblock can be used to block Google Anal, no need for NoScript.

Comment: Why do so many people use Internet Explorer??? Such a PoS

Comment: Could we get an update on the stats?

Comment: I'm making a website which is aimed at a similar market as SO. I'm trying to figure out whether I really need to support IE or not, and if so, which versions of it. So an updated table would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Why would SE aid in creating a potential competitor?

Comment: @NewWorld - Why wouldn't they? They've stated their primary goal is to aid developers. Much like Tesla wants more good alternatives to gasoline based cars to exist, Stack Exchange wants to spread knowledge. That they do it themselves isn't particularly important - the mission is bigger than the company. Anyways, I said it would have a similar audience, not be a competitor. Also, it is now possible for anyone with 25K or more reputation to view these stats at any time.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare That's very naive thinking. If the mission was more important than the company, why hasn't the site's source code and resources been released for public use? See the founders' [commenting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14658/254905) on this.

Comment: @NewWorld - Once you post something on the Internet, you can't take it back. I think that's a major fear with the idea of making the code open source. They're for it in theory, but cautious about it. They can always publish it in the future, but once they do, it can't be undone. Also, once it's out there, you're kind of responsible for making sure it stays up to date - it's an extra thing your company has to do. You don't want to expose internal plans accidentally. It's easier to keep something closed source than open source.

Answer (score 2):

I read from the iPhone on the trains, but I don't reply for two reasons. 1: It's too damn slow, and 2: more often than not, there's a bit of a bug where every time I write a letter the page jumps around like a teenager at Pearl Jam concert and it hurts my eyes.

Comment: I wonder if thats related to the key press Javascript that is updated the XX characters left message.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of the guys could post some of the GA statistics? I suppose that the Browser / Resoultion percentages won't need to be treated as secrets.

Answer (score 1):

[I use ...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/)

Answer (score 1):

We could do with this being updated: [User agent stats that visit SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66921/user-agent-stats-that-visit-se-sites)

Answer (score -1):

I personally browse from two different locations. At home I am generally on a laptop using Firefox and a 1280x1024 resolution. At work I am generally on Firefox from a 22" monitor doing 1680x1050.

I generally only browse the site on my iPhone if I am waiting somewhere to pick up my wife and I have nothing better to do.

Comment: I could have sworn that this question was CW. Oh well, switched my answer over just in case.

Comment: What about the ranch?

Comment: +1: because you did not have a +1 yet and it appeared to deserve 1.  Why?  No idea...

Comment: I'm not really after personal anecdotes, just overall stats.