# Which browsers does Stack Overflow support/recommend?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users, browsers

I know Stack Overflow can be used with almost every browser today, but I have a few more specific questions:

- Which browser do the developers suggest to use for Stack Overflow?
- What percent of users use a particular browser (Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari)?
- Does the SO team have a graph representing the above statistics?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15598/what-are-the-browser-and-resolution-stats-for-so-users

Comment: If you're considering changing your browser based on getting the best StackOverflow experience, you need to get out of the house a little more often.

Answer (score 12):

[alt text http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/195/browser.jpg](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/195/browser.jpg)

Comment: This picture could use 100 words.

Comment: Naw -- just needed to use a bigger brush for the freehand circle.

Comment: Oh, if only. Shame that the design of stackoverflow treats non-JS users as second-class citizens.

Comment: Non-JS users are second class citizens. Or conspiracy theorists.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/upgrade.html) for one reason: [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748).  There are tons of great grease monkey [scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) out there for `M?S[FOU]`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `S[FOU]`?

Comment: @mmyers Good point, thanks.  I didn't mean to reference the hidden site `S|`

Comment: really, should be `M?S[OFU]`  (note: meta.serverfault.com and meta.superuser.com redirect to meta.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

I dumped IE for Chrome because SO is SLOW on IE. It's all that fancy-pants client side stuff, especially when hiding/highlighting tags.

Comment: I dumped IE for anything else because everything is SLOW on IE.

Comment: you were still using IE when SO came out?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer: any browser.

Comment: ... or IE 9 Beta ;-)