# User agent stats that visit SE sites

Tags: discussion, status-completed, statistics

Are there any stats on the user agents that visit the SE sites? So you can tell how many browsers/devices are used to visit SE sites.

Not only will this be interesting, but useful for stackapp developers to see how much of the SE community use the browser/device their app needs and how far their app has gone.

15 upvotes is quite a lot and yet answer from anyone!!!

Comment: I'd like to ask this as well - I'm curious how many iOS devices you have browsing.

Comment: Here are the stats from a little over a year ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15598/what-are-the-browser-and-resolution-stats-for-so-users

Comment: I saw that already, but a lot has changed in a year, (eg there wasn't an ipad then, browser shares changed, IE9 can be downloaded). But it's good because it means that it's not that hard to get the stats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/

Comment: Finally ;) but I was hoping for more detail on the OSs?

Comment: Are you planning on doing another update? I'd be interested to see how the OS usage has changed.

Comment: Just give us automated updates. We're a community full of programmers. We're interested in knowing what browsers we need to support and which ones we can finally drop support for. I'm making a website for programmers, so I figure it'll end up getting a similar browser breakdown to what SO does. Such a tool could be built into the SO query engine thingamabop.