# Does Stack Overflow publish OS/browser usage usage stats?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm interested in seeing which OSes and browsers developers use and I'm sure Stack Overflow has some interesting data. Has any ever been released anywhere?

Comment: That just contains browser and resolution stats. Is there any information on OS usage?

Comment: Poke http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66921/user-agent-stats-that-visit-se-sites, maybe :)

Comment: Thanks, given it a go :)