# Updated stats on browsers used on SE

Tags: discussion, statistics, browsers

I was [wondering](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/update-to-mathjax-2-7-2-please) yesterday what fraction of SE visitors use Safari, but it turned out that the easily-discoverable resources,

- [What are the browser and resolution stats for SO users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15598/what-are-the-browser-and-resolution-stats-for-so-users)
- [User agent stats that visit SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66921/user-agent-stats-that-visit-se-sites)
- [Browsers and Screen Size on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/08/21/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/)
- [Stack Overflow 2010 Analytics](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/15/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/)

are all over seven years old. As such: is there a resource with statistics for what browsers, OSs, user agents, and resolutions are more or less used by visitors to the SE network, ideally updated yearly so that it won't age horribly like the previous ones?

Comment: [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#/crossPlatformCard) shows mobile vs. web, which might be interesting but too coarse for your purposes.

Comment: There is a [`site-analytics`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) privilege once you reach 25K. This is **not** shown there.