# Should we stop supporting Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: discussion, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

As of January 12, 2016, Internet Explorer 10 is no longer supported on consumer versions of Windows (with Windows 7 users updating to IE11, and Windows 8 users upgrading to 8.1 which includes IE11). The last update was in December 2016, to fix a critical security bug.

We are beginning to [face bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363864/editor-toolbar-layout-broken-in-ie-10) due to using features that are not supported in IE10. While it is prudent to dismiss those bugs as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because IE10 is outdated, this cannot be done at the moment. According to [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), IE10 is a supported browser. (It says it supports the last two major versions of every major browser, of which Internet Explorer is one. Thus, by definition, IE10 is supported.)

Should we stop supporting IE10? Does the current status of the system warrant it at the moment?

According to animuson [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363864/editor-toolbar-layout-broken-in-ie-10?noredirect=1#comment561130_363864)...

> That's like saying we indefinitely support IE10 because there will never be a version 12+. Not gonna happen. [...] Otherwise it's safe to say IE10 is unsupported.

I'm loath to edit that post to say that IE10 is unsupported until I get a formal response from the team as to whether or not this should be done.

Comment: Noo... (nodding *yes*)

Comment: IMO critical bugs (i.e. blocking users from posting or editing) should still be fixed, but non critical bugs (e.g. design) should be dismissed with "browser too old".

Comment: I would highly recommend adopting a policy of only supporting browsers still supported by the vendor. Otherwise you can end up in a rabbit hole that never ends of pain.

Comment: There is no basis for anyone ever drawing a cut-off at IE10. It represents ~0 users, and doesn't offer much more functionality than IE9. IE9 may be the appropriate conservative choice for some organizations. IE11 is appropriate for many more. IE10 is the appropriate choice for nobody. *You hear that, former former manager of mine?! We don't need to support it!* 

Comment: Eventually we're going to drop IE10 support. When? No idea. But honestly, developing a strict policy on this is incredibly low on the priority list right now. It simply doesn't matter - we'll make things work as much as we reasonably can in the meantime like we always have with IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 support has been officially dropped, per [this edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/71208/96) to the list of supported browsers from an SE employee.

As such, this discussion is now moot.

Answer (score 12):

More important than what is supported by Microsoft is what is actually used by people browsing the Stack Exchange network. Considering the lag a lot of corporate standard browsers have and the laziness a lot of consumers apply to software updates it will be quite a while until something that's not supported anymore is not used anymore.

If it were my decision I'd look at the amount of people still using the version and decide at which point that number is low enough to stop supporting them. That doesn't really have anything to do with official Microsoft support for the browser.

Comment: heh, I was looking for statistics but the most recent I can find is from 2010. [There's a request for more updated stats here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300640/updated-stats-on-browsers-used-on-se)

Comment: You forgot Government employees or contractors. These people do constitute a rather large group of users, and are also often forced to work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: I was replying to a specific comment.  You asked how the two sentences were related.  I explained any US government system not running Windows 10 is a system that is physically isolated from the internet. I was trying to provide information that might not be known.  *Any event, it’s time to stop supporting an insecure unsupported version of IE.*. I can see that information sharing isn’t appreciated.  So I will take my ball and go home.

Comment: No, Government agencies are required to update to Windows 10 on all machines, however, there will be systems not upgraded but those systems are physically isolated from the internet already so they don’t really count

Comment: I don't think this is actually an option in the IE10 case, disabling TLS 1.0 and SSL 3.0 will do the job of effectively banning IE10 anyway. Moreover generally speaking IE10 usage has always been lower than IE 9 and IE 11. In most corporate environments they have enterprise chrome or firefox as well to support sites that don't support IE. I think this is a non issue that is effectively overridden by security concerns anyway.

Comment: IE10 was the latest version on Windows 7 for a very short amount of time (February-November 2013), and it's likely that Windows 7 users would use either IE8 or 11. The original Windows 8 went unsupported on January 12, 2016, and the only way to update IE on it is to upgrade to Windows 8.1, but usage share of that OS is very low.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek caniuse.com reports IE10 usage at 0.13% global.

Comment: @Ano the only supported IE version on windows 7 is IE11. Microsoft has gone to a policy of only supporting the latest version of IE that any given version of windows supports. I don't recommend under any circumstances supporting a browser that the vendor is not supporting or releasing patches for.

Comment: @Mgetz Hence the request for SE to stop supporting IE10. In fact, I said in the question that the last patch was in December 2016.