# Sanity check with browser support

Tags: support, browsers

> we support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority
>   of our visitors actually use.

[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161)

> We're committed to supporting the current version and one previous major
>   version of major browsers.

[Should Stack Exchange support ESR releases of Firefox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143184)

I find this definition problematic. Take for example Firefox, using this
definition yields these 2 versions:

- Firefox 61: June 26, 2018
- Firefox 60: May 9, 2018

With the version before that being:

Firefox 59: March 13, 2018

So are we really saying that that we dont support a 5 month old browser? I am asking
because people are referencing this definition:

[comment flags broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313444/comment-flags-broken)

Version reference:

http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history

Also someone mention this question:

[Should we stop supporting Internet Explorer 10?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307455)

however in that question the browser was 6 years old which is quite different
from 5 months.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307455/should-we-stop-supporting-internet-explorer-10

Comment: "So are we really that that we dont support a 5 month old browser?" Why should we?  Are lots of people 1) using those old browsers 2) having problems as a result of their browsers being out of date 3) problems that can be effectively solved by SO without those users updating their browsers, in a small enough amount of time that it's worth SO's effort to allow these users to use these older browsers?  When you've demonstrated that those points are met, that's when it becomes worthwhile to support those older browsers.  My guess is #2 will be the biggest roadblock personally.

Comment: @StevenPenny That's the answer you want for your question.  I was asking for you to answer the questions that I asked you.  Again, are people actually using those browser versions, are they not working, and can the problems causing them to not work be effectively fixed by the SO team?  Saying that they're "only 5 months old" doesn't answer those questions.

Comment: Two versions doesn't mean the same thing as when that was written, @serv, he's right. It's archaic. For Firetox or Chrome, the modern equivalent would be to support their Stable and LTS channels.

Comment: @SomethingBadHappened The release schedules aren't any more frequent now then they were at the time of the earlier post Firefox has been on frequent releases since 2011, many years before that policy was put in place.  In fact, it was put in place *because* of that change in how browsers were released (supporting so many different browser versions to go back even a short span of time is just untenable, SE couldn't do it, hence the change).

Comment: From the point of SE, it's probably unreasonable to cater support to outdated browsers as well as up-to-date browsers, as it requires more development work and testing. They already have to test multiple platforms and browsers. Adding more than a couple versions per browser is asking a lot. Most users update their browsers automatically. https://caniuse.com/usage-table

Comment: I also had issue with Ububtu (18 I think?). I discovered that if I click the visible corner of the flag dialog and then hit any key, it jumps back to center of screen.