# Comment flag box stuck in top left, can't reach any option

Tags: bug, user-interface

When I try to flag a comment, the flag comment box is in the top left and I can't select any option.

[image: Flag box top right]

This does not happen consistently. Sometimes it ends up in the correct place. Sometimes it jumps to the middle when I perform an action.

I'm using Firefox 56.0 here, but I've also seen the behaviour in a recent version of Pale Moon.

Comment: tl:dr; on that one is that your browser is unsupported, and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313867/369403) about prolonging browser support followed quickly after that one.