# Is Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow available for private or internal use?

Tags: support, faq, stack-exchange, so-engine, so-enterprise

Is the Stack Exchange engine that powers Stack Overflow available to download or install internally for an enterprise or company?

I think Stack Exchange's engine is very great and could be very cool to use for internal enterprise patterns and practices, like the engine of Wikipedia.

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: Alternatively, some [stack exchange clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones) are free/open source.

Comment: Once they are implemented, [Stack Overflow Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352065/2157640) might become an alternative to Stack Exchange Enterprise for those wanting a simple private Q&A.

Comment: how about a public facing, enterprise version for questions relating to that enterprises developer community / api?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

[**Stack Overflow for Teams is free for 50 users**](https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/teams-free?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=campaign-28&utm_content=post-2)

If you aren’t familiar with Stack Overflow for Teams, it combines the best features of the Stack Overflow platform with features tailored for teams and companies who need a private knowledge sharing and collaboration platform such as Articles, Collections and integrations. Check out our [Product Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/tour) page to learn more about these features.

It is free for up to 50 users.

- No credit card is required to start your Team, and it’s free forever.
- Our Free plan includes ChatOps integrations to Slack and Microsoft
  Teams.
- We have invested in a guided onboarding process to help admins
  and users experience value quickly and efficiently.

We have 3 other paid plans with additional features:

- Basic - includes the same ChatOps integrations as free and offers SSO and additional support options. The maximum number of users is 250.
- Business - same features as Basic plus long-form content (Articles), GitHub, Jira and Okta integrations, the Collections feature, and a usage and adoption dashboard. Unlimited users.
- Enterprise - same features as Business plus additional hosting, securing, and support options.

You can find the most up to date pricing for those plans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing).

If you prefer a more public-facing site, we have [150+ sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) to [**help support your developer community**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community). But if you cannot find a Stack Exchange site in your area of interest, we have a place where you can propose one. "Area 51" is a community-driven process where groups of experts come together to build new Q&A sites that work just like Stack Overflow. You can [read more about the site proposal process here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Does the enterprise edition use the latest engine and get all the improvements as they happen or is it the old white label 1.0 version?

Comment: @LoremIpsum Stack Overflow Enterprise has been updated to use the ***current*** version of Stack Overflow. With a dedicated Enterprise team, they have also added features which are unique to the Enterprise environment.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Unfortunately no. I don't believe there is fixed pricing available. Pricing depends on the requirements and hosting arrangements needed by the customer.

Comment: Great ! Is the new **Documentation feature** available in Stack Overflow Enterprise edition? Thanks

Comment: @RomainX. We definitely want to offer it in Enterprise, but Documentation is still early in development, so we want to give the Documentation team time to get it right in public beta... and then we'll look at a timeline to incorporate it into our Enterprise product.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Is there a mailing list or blog one could sign up to/follow for announcements of things such as when Documentation is available for Enterprise?

Comment: @Binarytales Most of our major announcements are posted to http://blog.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: If I want a "more public-facing site", but wish to host it separately / wrap a website around it (no problem attributing credit to Stack Exchange, on the contrary really) - is the Enterprise solution for me or not? Thanks!

Comment: @RobertCartaino multilanguage is possible? or only English?

Comment: @Oray I don't see a reason the software couldn't be used for a non-English audience, but translating the UI to other languages is not currently on our roadmap. And the administrators it would need to speak English to effectively communicate with us regarding any sales or technical support issues. Enterprise does not have dedicated support staff for non-English audiences.

Comment: @RobertCartaino are you aware whether an Educational version of Enterprise for use within Universities is available? We are interested in promoting the use of sites like StackOverflow with students.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Documentation project was stopped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/2157640), @Romain. Probably, you will not see anything similar in Stack Exchange Enterprise anytime soon.

Comment: @selig, There is an (pseudo) Educational version of Teams now https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367590/4099593