# Where can I get a Stack Overflow-like site to use as my company's knowledge base?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, private-site

Where can I get a Stack Overflow-like site to use as my company's knowledge base?

Comment: The hard part is getting trolls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>The engine used in Stack Overflow is sold as [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/).</s>

**Edit:** The paid Stack Exchange service was ended in [April 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/). There are several [Stack Exchange-like systems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) that may be suitable for corporate users instead.

Comment: how much is it? and how to buy?

Comment: wasn't it reimplemented in November in a different form? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available/16055#16055

Comment: @Brandon: I'd forgotten about that. Does an edit of an existing post in November count as an official announcement? If they changed their minds, would they remember to have someone re-edit that post?

Comment: Posting a new comment because the old one can't be edited anymore. The history of Enterprise SE: Joel mentioned it [on May 5th, 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-overflow-funding-chat-qa-transcript/). But in June, [Robert said it was gone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions/55260#55260). Then in November, Michael Pryor confirmed twice; once where Brandon linked and once [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69362/are-there-going-to-be-public-details-about-the-enterprise-version-of-se/69436#69436).

Comment: From the limited information available, I'm guessing this is being downplayed intentionally. It makes sense; the Enterprise Edition isn't really for anyone who would casually post a question here asking about it. Anyone who _is_ in Enterprise's target audience would have his people contact Joel's people to "do lunch."

Answer (score 2):

I would propose an update on this topic and consider [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) which makes it easy to search and find answers in a private and secure environment.