# Are there going to be public details about the enterprise version of SE?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, so-enterprise

Apparently it is possible to [purchase a Stack Exchange site again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197549/98786).

What is considered a large organization? Google/Apple/MS sized organizations? Obviously it will cost a fair bit, but any information for those of us who don't want to pretend to represent a huge company? Not that it wouldn't be fun, but it would ultimately be a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I'm expecting a blog entry sometime, but there doesn't seem to be anything yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes! There's now some basic information available on the **[Stack Overflow Enterprise site](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise)**.

The big picture idea though is that SO Enterprise is a private version of the Stack Overflow engine that you use on the public site every day - it's just set up in a private environment (either a private cloud or on-premises) and only accessible to the employees of a company.  We use a shared code base between the public and Enterprise versions of the site, so it looks and acts just like the real thing (plus a few customizations and features like SSO support).

If you do happen to work for a large company (think 500+ developers), you can [request more information and a demo](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise/request-a-demo) and the sales team will reach out to you.