# possible to puchase stackoverflow for own site?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to purchase something like a premium version of this script so that enterprises can use it on their own site?

We are sick and tired of vbulletin type of forum based systems.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267 there are some promising candidates - probably none as polished as SOFU, but some come close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, see this post: [Are there going to be public details about the enterprise version of SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69362/are-there-going-to-be-public-details-about-the-enterprise-version-of-se/69436#69436)