# Embed Stack Overflow in my site

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I love the functionality of Stack Overflow.  However, I'd like to embed a version in my site.

Ideally, it would need the following features:

1. I can remove the overwhelming Stack Overflow branding and replace with smaller "Powered by Stack Overflow"
2. I can filter the results to limit the available sets of data provided to my users (subsets only)

Does this functionality exist?  If so, can you provide a link? If so, does Stack Overflow provide detailed terms, conditions and limitations of this service?

Comment: "overwhelming" branding? It is their site. Can I steal your site and choose how I want your branding to be?

Comment: I'd like, to be classic, a pony.

Comment: whatevs === grain of salt (overwhelming branding) vs wound (can't embed stackoverflow in my site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no can do.  But you might contact the team directly to see if they're interested in pursuing that form of marketing.  The email is at the bottom of this page ('contact us').

Answer (score 7):

No, you can not. But many others have asked similar questions.

[Is the Stack Exchange engine available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054/169404) as well as [Are there going to be public details about the enterprise version of SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69362/169404) which had the response:

> It's for internal use only (i.e. not public internet) and it's only for large institutions (think big banks, or Google/Apple/MS type orgs).

Check out [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/169404) if you are interested in running your own because their are many open source knock offs.

*However*, if you want the community and the data, then the only way is to use SE as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow for Teams seems to be the the answer, these days.

https://stackoverflow.com/teams

In short:

> Today’s new thing is called Stack Overflow for Teams. It lets you set up a private place on Stack Overflow where you can ask questions that will only be visible to members of your team, company, or organization. It is a paid service, but it’s not expensive.

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/05/03/announcing-stack-overflow-for-teams/