# What does Stack Exchange sell?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

If you go here: https://stackexchange.com/about/team, there are people who are working on sales or product manager.

What do they do?

Comment: whoa .. there is only ~22 developer in 72 people team

Comment: @NullPointer The number by him self is not good criterion - for example if you place two engines together in a cars this will be run faster or slower ?

Comment: There's an old saying: if the service is free to you, you're not the customer, you're the product

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They sell ad placement, job postings on careers 2.0, and [Stack Exchange software to large businesses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69362/169404).

Comment: Ad placements? I have never seen an ad here on SE sites.

Comment: @socr19991293 They are usually ads for other SE sites. If you have low rep, you will have more/bigger ads on the page. But yes, I see Careers 2.0 ads every single day.

Comment: There are also sponsored tags.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Which ones ? o.O

Comment: @AshRj http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/sponsored-tags/info contains all the information, there is currently no list though. Example for very popular sponsored tag: [tag:android] as you see, there is list of sponsored links.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nice. Do you know who suggested/thought-of it ?

Comment: @AshRj looks like it exists from the very beginning of Stack Overflow, or early after. Who thought of it? Most likely either Jeff or Joel.