# How do you go about creating a Stack site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Is it possible to create a Stack site for support/questions about a private website? I have a client at the moment for whom this type of Q&A site would be ideal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Stack Exchange engine available for use?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available-for-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

Stack Exchange 1.0 was available but didn't work as expected so Stack Exchange 2.0 was launched over at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) as a community driven approach. You propose a site and if enough people support it, it goes into beta mode. If there's enough traffic it emerges as a fully fledged site.