# How does the monetization process of a StackExchange site work?

Tags: support, area-51, stack-exchange, business-model

Suppose I propose a site. Let's say it is approved (xyz.stackexchange.com). Now, when it becomes full-fledged and 'independent' I know the content is licensed under creative commons so anyone can use it. However:

1. Is there a concept of who is the 'creator' of the website? Who makes the decisions like what will be the final site name, etc.?
2. Who earns from the ads on the website (or any type of monetization)?
   a) When the site is in beta stage (still an SE site).
   b) When the site is *independent*.
3. Is it a usual practice that initial contributors (active participants, users with high rep) are 'stakeholders' or even rewarded in some way out of courtesy? Do people usually come together and form teams, and then start their own venture out of an SE site?

I am confused after reading the [area 51 faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and posts like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available/16056#16056). 
I am very much interested to know about the process/options but right now I don't know enough to even ask the right questions, though this is a start.

Comment: You should check out some of the blog posts on this. Namely, [this one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) to start and maybe [this one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/migration-of-se-1-0-sites/). While old, the matters of money haven't actually changed since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Is there a concept of who is the 'creator' of the website. Who makes the decisions like what will be the final site name, etc.

- The creator is the community - all those who put time and effort into making the site possible.  They aren't afforded any particular special privileges, though.  Naming is hard, but it's liable to be community driven, with the final decision resting with Stack Overflow Internet Services.

2) Who earns from the ads on the website (or any type of monetization)?
a) When the site is in beta stage (still an SE site)
b) When the site is independent.

- In both cases, Stack Overflow Internet Services owns, operates, and profits from the sites.

3) Is it a usual practice that initial contributors (active participants, users with high rep) are 'stakeholders' or even rewarded in some way out of courtsey? Do people usually come together and form teams, and then start their own venture out of an SE site?

- Initial contributors may receive a "beta" badge, and perhaps another badge or two the depend on early participation, but they are not given anything else for their work.
- I have not heard of any endeavors that sprung from a Stack Exchange 2.0 site.

---

The previous incarnation of Stack Exchange allowed individuals and companies to subscribe to the Stack Exchange engine as a service, and therefore run their own Q&A sites and profit from the ads thereon.

This is no longer the case - that service was discontinued some time ago, and the last sites on there will be shut down in a few months.

Those that want to pursue this sort of business outside the control of Stack Overflow Internet Services have the option of adopting one of many [stackoverflow-like clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) that have been developed over the last few years.

Comment: can you post links to some of the individual or business owned SO v1 websites(if possible)?

Comment: @abel - Please check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-1-0-sites - Note that the list is old and not updated, so many sites may no longer be around.  I know that http://www.moms4mom.com is still around, and I believe that http://www.mathoverflow.com is still separate.

Comment: Does Meta.SE also use SO v1?It wont recognize my openid. Thx for the list

Comment: As of a few days ago, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites no longer exists. All `meta.stackexchange.com` URLs redirect to the MSO main page.