# How can I start my own overflow site?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Stack Exchange engine available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available)

I have some ideas for cool sites like:

femaleOverflow.com - Q&A for understanding women
lifeOverfllow.com - sharing life experiences
ethicsOverflow.com - you know this will be endless

But how do I actually make them?

Comment: You start by naming them ~.StackExchange not ~Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to propose a new site at http://area51.stackexchange.com/ , but I am not sure that could attract existing users though.