# Creating Q&A for our own site using Stack Exchange engine?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, subdomains, personalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Stack Exchange engine available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available)

Is it possible (or planned) to sell stack overflow as a service, so we can create Q&A for our own site, maybe link it to our own domain, and benefit using such a great platform?

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not planned.

A long time ago, the Stack Exchange engine was licensed, resulting in what is now known as the "Stack Exchange 1.0" network of sites. That didn't go so well and the program was canceled.

In its stead, the "Stack Exchange 2.0" program was announced. Run from the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), this allows users to propose new Q&A sites on a particular topic that should be added to the network. The new ideas are proposed, discussed, and built on the Area 51 site. The sites that have built up a critical mass of support and appear most likely to be successful will be launched in "beta".

If you think there is a need for a new Q&A site in the Stack Exchange network, you should propose it on Area 51 and get your friends to support it!

For further reading, check out [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) by Joel Spolsky, which documents the changes made to SE network as it transitioned from the SE 1.0 model to the current SE 2.0 model.

**Update:**
As Mark points out in the comments, [there is a Stack Exchange Enterprise option available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16055/153008) for internal use by large organizations. If you might be interested in this option, use the contact link found at the bottom of each page to send an inquiry email to the team.

Comment: I know a group that would probably like to purchase a private hosted Stack instance (if only they knew it) but what's crazy to think about is that if they couldn't get a site out of Area 51, it probably wouldn't justify the cost and hassle of running a _private_ site for them. Metcalfe's Law (or observation...) is a strange thing...

Comment: @sarnold just pick one from a ton of SO [clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/167396)

Comment: @om-nom: That's awesome, thanks. (Amazing how a recent +200 post can so easily slip past.)

Comment: This is not entirely accurate: there is a [white label version of Stack Exchange still available for internal use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16055/149432) provided you have the money.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, I didn't know that. I suppose it's still accurate; Grace indicates it is as of July '11. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

However, there is a number of [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) available, some of which have become pretty mature.