# Can I use Stack Overflow or one of its Stack Exchange sites to store a knowledgebase for our in-house product?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Stack Exchange engine available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available)

> Adding on to this question -
>
> [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

We are a small organization and we have an in-house product (framework) of our own. We are trying to get a repository where we can store and share the knowledgebase of our product. So basically what we are looking at is similar to Stack Overflow where people(employees and clients) can ask questions and our team can answer them. Building this infrastructure ourselves is a costly process for us, hence we would like to know few items -

1. Can we use Stack Overflow to maintain questions and answers related to our product under a new tag? (risk is SO community might close the question as irrelevant)
2. If not, then can we have host one of the new Stack Exchange sites for our own use?
3. Since the questions asked on our product are applicable only to a small community of people(around 500), can we have some kind of closed community where we can allow users to access this Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Use one of the open source SO clones.