# Is there a way to see votes (counts) before and after an answer is made Community Wiki?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, community-wiki

I had [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available/16055#16055) here on Meta that was accepted and got a few upvotes. (The question is asking about using the Stack Exchange engine internally in a different organization.)

Michael Pryor later came along and, instead of creating a new answer, simply updated my answer (I assume because it was already accepted). Since none of my original answer was left, I felt the ethical thing to do was to make it Community Wiki; I shouldn't get Reputation points off Michael's answer.

Anyway, I was wondering how many votes the answer has gotten since the conversion to Community Wiki. I guess I want to see how many Reputation points I've foregone by taking the high road. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There's probably some fancy query for it, but if you don't mind doing it ugly and manually you could always look at [the timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/16054/timeline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Data.SE  (which is kept fairly up to date these days).

[Here's a query I wrote](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/96499/votes-after-wiki?PostId=16055)

And here's the current results

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╗
║ VoteDate  Name                   ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2011-02-18 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 UpMod                 ║
║ 2011-01-31 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 UpMod                 ║
║ 2010-11-04 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 UpMod                 ║
║ 2010-10-05 UpMod                 ║
║ 2011-02-10 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 UpMod                 ║
║ 2011-03-27 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 UpMod                 ║
║ 2011-02-18 UpMod                 ║
║ 2011-03-17 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 UpMod                 ║
║ 2010-10-05 UpMod                 ║
║ 2011-02-17 UpMod                 ║
║ 2009-08-21 AcceptedByOriginator  ║
║ 2010-10-05 UpMod                 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╝
```

18 UpMods, 1 AcceptedByOriginator   = 195 points

[Here's a version with sums of before and after](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/96504/votes-after-wiki-sums?PostId=16055)