# Duplicate question order

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

I just saw that [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166831/is-it-possible-to-integrate-stack-overflow-in-my-website) got closed with the following votes: 
1 vote  for a duplicate of [stack-overflow-clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/) and 
4 votes for a duplicate of [is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/).

But the question with only 1 vote get listed first. Is that on purpose or just random?

I suggest to list the most close-voted on question first.

Comment: I was the first to vote to close it as the first duplicate. So it's most likely an order thing.

Comment: The question listed first has 330 votes, the other has 39. I'd rather see the _canonical_ question at the top of the list. This is conjecture, though. Will need to check the code to confirm.

Comment: Looks like it's already done from here...