# Can a site created on area 51 not to be public?

Tags: support, area-51

I know at beta stage the site ill get private access. But I want to create a site and keep access restricted.

We are a IT Company with hundreds developers from many backgrounds and we need something like Stack Overflow for the company knowledge base.

We also need to access this knowledge base form anywhere, no just at intranet.
But we want to prevent people out of corporation to view that base.

Can StackOverflow create a non public site?

Comment: Do note that there is a Stack Exchange Enterprise option available for large corporations to have their own non-public site on their intranet. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available/16055#16055

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  The SE system is specifically designed to create strictly public sites.

Once upon a time the feature you're requesting did exist (or something close to it anyway) and it has long since been deprecated.

From the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **Do you offer "white-label" or subscription hosting for Stack Exchange sites?**
>
> Unfortunately, we no longer offer a subscription service or license the software to host Stack Exchange sites. Stack Exchange sites can only be created via the democratic, community-driven process at Area 51. We offer neither "white-label" services, nor the ability to bypass Area 51 to create sites through partnerships.

The following question is also related:

> **Can I use Stack Exchange to support my product?**
>
> Stack Exchange does not offer a private label service for owning a Q&A site. You are free to create an expert Q&A site in your area of expertise. There is a lot of visibility and credibility to becoming a central figure in an expert community, but Stack Exchange is a product for the Internet community at large, not for corporations or individuals.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, ill check it. We want support for a product nor a subscription hosting. Just a nice tool to share (sometimes sensible) knowledge between coworkers.

Comment: @jean It's the details of the questions that are relevant however.  To pick out the more specific relevant quotes: "We offer neither [...] the ability to bypass Area 51 to create sites through partnerships", "Stack Exchange does not offer a private label service for owning a Q&A site", and "Stack Exchange is a product for the Internet community at large, not for corporations or individuals."  These make it pretty clear that they won't create a private site just for your company.

Comment: Yes Servy, I got that. My previous comment was more a apology. I'm rethinking about all this. Most knowledge here is about open technologies and things we can share on a public site. Maybe we can create a regular site and in case of any sensible info link it to a protected repository.