# Pricing model for using Stack Exchange

Tags: support, cost

We are evaluating a different forum solution for our business need.

- Can we use Stack Exchange?
- Is there any enterprise version?
- What is the pricing model?
- Is there any on-premise solution or everything is in the cloud?
- If we need to develop new features, should we have access to the code or need to go through Stack Exchange development team?
- How much we can customize?
- What is the account manager's contact info for Europe?
- Can we import content from another forum?
- Gold support? What is the SLA for customer support?

Many thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: The answer by [Robert](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available-for-use/197549#197549) gives details on who to contact about using Stack Overflow Enterprise.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681). Besides that, [the latest podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/podcast-71-a-bunch-of-bald-yaks/) had some information that may answer your very question.

Comment: Send an email to "enterprise@stackoverflow.com" two days ago, still waiting for a reply. Is there any phone number I can call?