# How would I get a Stack Exchange site created for my product?

Tags: discussion

Is the creation of sites dedicated to one specific product something that is decided by the Stack Exchange community and team based on popularity of the product, or can companies pay to have one hosted in the network?

Comment: Consider also: **[How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community)**. The guidance there also applies to project teams in *other* subjects beyond software development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the creation of sites dedicated to one specific product something that is decided by the Stack Exchange community and team based on popularity of the product

Yes, essentially it is. There is a whole process for suggesting new sites - take a look at our [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) and its [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for details.

The general process is for someone to propose a new topic (which does not usually mean any specific product). This proposal needs to show support from the community - people that follow and commit to its success. With enough of these, a new site will be stood up in a private beta. These don't always succeed - those that do move to a public beta (at this point it will be considered part of the network, though in beta status), which, if successful, will eventually launch as a fully fledged site on the network.

Most of the proposed sites have nothing to do products, by the way. When we do start up a site that is related to a product (for example, we have a few CMS sites), it would have gone through the Area 51 process.

> can companies pay to have one hosted in the network?

Yes and no... we do offer [Stack Exchange Enterprise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197549/140505) which is a hosted option for companies. But - these are **not** part of the network. They are for internal use by the companies who purchase this product.

---

If you want a Stack Exchange style Q&A site, you can certainly try out one of the [many existing clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/140505). Most of these are free, but are also not part of the network - they are usually a shallow clone of the general UI.

Comment: What I had in mind was to support our product's user base (we have an ERP) rather than the developers. Especially with the new Documentation product currently being tested with Stack Overflow, the tool set offered by Stack Exchange could be very useful in enabling our own user community to help itself.

Comment: @Stuporman - Documentation is currently in Beta, so not part of a commercial offering (at this point). As I said - you can always suggest a community on Area 51, but it would need community support to become part of the network. I don't believe we have a commercial offering that will work as you expect, but by all means, contact the enterprise team to find out.