# Import public Stack Overflow into Stack Overflow Enterprise

Tags: support, so-enterprise

Can you import all of public Stack Overflow into your private instance of Stack Overflow Enterprise? Or, link it to your private Enterprise instance while keeping locally created content private?

Comment: Is this a feature request or a support question?  What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: Are you really saying that you want to import all of the bajillion SO questions? That seems like it defeats the entire purpose of a private Instance.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this to themselves

Comment: Some people enjoy hair shirts, and long walks over burning lava?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure I'm addressing your question because it's not really clear what you are trying to do. But however you frame this, the answer is almost certainly no — or at least it would be terribly impractical.

- Stack Overflow Enterprise is designed for large developer organizations to share internal knowledge about their organization's projects (see [about Enterprise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197549/98786)). This isn't a small undertaking (or expense) that someone is going to take on without *great* benefit.
- Stack Overflow (public) has over 33 million posts with almost 8,000 new questions coming in daily. The storage and bandwidth needed to transfer all that content (questions, answers, votes, comments, flags, meta data, activity) is gargantuan. The responsibilities and mechanisms needed to keep that all up to date are substantial.
- Stack Overflow Enterprise is a separate product from the public website. It includes features, behaviors, and security considerations specific to the an internal, privately-hosted resource. Even if you managed to copy over all the data from the live SO site, anything proprietary you added would be wiped out by the next update. The two system are just *not* designed to look out for each other.

Comment: Could you seed it once at the start with just all questions from a certain tag, say: Haskell?

Comment: @rene No, we do not support that use case. I'm still not clear on why a company would want to pay to host a closed, static, proprietary copy of a free public website that is updated and growing constantly. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Instead of importing it all could you stitch the two sources together in one UI?

Comment: No, these Enterprise systems are installed behind secured private networks for a reason. Nobody wants their company's internal enterprise calling out to a public website to exchange posts at great risk of making private information very public. It's a security nightmare.