# Create a Q & A community with less than 100 members

Tags: discussion

If one wishes to use a format similar to stack exchange with only friends from college or coworkers, what would be the best way around it?

Facebook is too permissive of spam and apps like WhatsApp are too far from the idea

Edit: I had already read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-stack-exchange-stack-overflow-available-for-private-or-internal-use), but it's oriented to organizations with more than 500 members:

> Enterprise is a self-sustaining community, built for large organizations that generally plan to support 500 or more users.

Comment: "but it's oriented to organizations with more than 500 members" - so what? If there will be something for smaller organization, answer will fit there, not here.

Comment: You could run one of the [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/135565)

Comment: I agree that my question is a duplicate and it currently has at least 3 downvotes. Without taking into account the effect to my reputation, would deleting this question be the _right_ thing to do?

Comment: I tried to delete it to get a "Peer pressure badge" but when I click delete, I get a message saying "We do not recommend deleting "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're only able to answer questions about Stack Exchange on this site, really.

At this point, there's not a way to make a tiny Q&A site like what you're talking about using the Stack Exchange software. There is a project in development ([Stack Overflow Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams?s=3|39.5238)) which would probably work for what you want but they will likely require some financial investment on the part of your group.

There are many options for forums around, though... but those aren't dedicated Q&A sites. You might find some help through our Community Building site. They do accept questions about establishing new communities but I'm not sure if they recommend products for hosting communities. You would need to check their [help](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages and [meta site](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain more about the forums? You mean my group creating a webpage that works like a forum?

Comment: I know that SE has enterprise systems that they have setup for university courses and companies. Whether that is still an active thing I don't know.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Pretty sure that 100 people is pretty small for enterprise. But I'm not sure... and I'm also pretty sure it's really expensive. The examples in the question are all free.

Comment: The rule of thumb seems to be *if you have to consider if you can afford SE Enterprise, you probably can't* but you can only find out by sending them an e-mail.