# Why does this question continue to show as Community Wiki, even though a moderator removed community wiki status?

Tags: support, specific-question, meta, community-wiki

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-stack-exchange-stack-overflow-available-for-private-or-internal-use) shows as being Community Wiki on the question page. However, if you check its [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/16054/revisions), it shows that a moderator removed Community Wiki status.

Additionally, I tried [answering that question as a test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315515/377214) (10k-only), and it was also marked as Community Wiki, by virtue of the question being such. There was no checkbox to select it for myself.

Why does it continue to show and behave as Community Wiki, even though a moderator removed its status?

Comment: Related note: [All 152 \[FAQ\] questions here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) are CW.  And **this is the policy that's stated** in [the \[faq-proposed\] wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq-proposed/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [appears](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/22534)* that removing Wiki status, then adding it again, only generates a **Mod Removes Wiki** revision history entry.

<sub>* I removed, edited, then re-added community wiki status to that post.</sub>

One would expect a subsequent **Post Made Community Wiki** revision, but this does not appear.

Perhaps a "made wiki" entry is only ever added once. Who knows - there is quite a long [history of weirdness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22post%20made%20community%20wiki%22) with CW revision history entries.

> Why does it continue to show and behave as Community Wiki, even though a moderator removed its status?

It was made Community Wiki again, but that action does not show in the revision history.

Comment: Can you try removing, editing, and then adding it back?