# Is source of SO free to use?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I want to have discussion site like SO for another purpose.

IS source of SO like sites https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites free?

From where i can download, can i use on any site for any purpose free.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/the-stackoverflow-source-code
and see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638/which-cms-or-other-framework-should-i-use-to-develop-a-stackoverflow-like-site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, StackExchange and StackOverflow are not open-source software.  However, you can pay a fee to use the stackexchange software [on your own site](http://stackexchange.com)<sup>1</sup>.

Alternatively, google for "open-source stackoverflow clone", which should give you a free alternative.

<sub>1 Apparently, stackexchange offers the first 45 days free as a trial</sub>

Comment: I need php/mysql based clone of like SO

Comment: Get to work creating it then :)

Comment: I think SO is based on .net framework

Comment: Yes, ASP.Net MVC I believe is what Joel said it was made with in some blog entry

Comment: @Jitendra the first google result I came up with is http://anantgarg.com/qwench/, which is hosted on github for you at http://github.com/anantgarg/Qwench

Answer (score 1):

You should see the [list of SO clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones), some of which [are open source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953), developed on the language the OP liked the most (Python, Ruby, PHP, ASP.Net).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download the source. Those sites are hosted by the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) platform.