# Can Stack Exchange's reputation system become usable programmatically?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange

I want to make a blog on which my friends will contribute posts and I want to maintain my contributors' reputation. The readers will thumb-up/down/etc. on posts. I don't want to write my own reputation system, but the one used here.

For example, Facebook provides social plugins (e.g. like, send, comments, recent activity, etc). The data is saved on Facebook servers but things work on our website. In my case, if we think abstractly, the blog posts' URLS are concepts on which anyone will be giving feedback (vote-up/down etc.).

There must be some way to use Stack Exchange's reputation system programmatically, so that we can send data when users give feedback and renders the reputation widget on some other page or at posts page.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to implement something *similar* to the reputation system on Stack Overflow? Or do you mean that you actually want to allow people to vote on SO posts from your own website?

Comment: Yes, I want to use (not implement, please note) reputation system similar to SO. Instead of implementing my own, I want to use SO reputations system as plugin. e.g. If we integrate Facebook Like button, user can Like our site. But we do not maintain the likes count, who liked, etc. in our database. But it is maintain on Facebook Servers. I want to use SO reputation system in same way. So the questions is, does SO has made such plugin or not yet?

Comment: No, they don't have that. Their source code is not available for public use ([reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40581/is-source-of-so-free-to-use)), and they haven't released any portions as closed-source plug-ins (I'm not even sure how that would work anyway).

Comment: For it, they don't need to make source-code public. The can do so by releasing close-source plugins (e.g. using Javascript or Web services etc). The logic will be something like, they have to treat URLs as concepts on which users can Vote-Up/Vote-Down or even assign  bades.

Comment: (in my case) these bades/votes will be assigned to Authors (indirectly), and when we call their service (using that plugin or API) with list of URLs (published by a particular author), they just  send/render a widgets with total Vote-Ups/Vote-Downs etc. with a link "Show Author Bades" that may open a pop-up, who will display the list of badges assigned to Posts or Authors. This is just a rough logic, can be optimized in many ways, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No such tool exists, nor is it likely to ever exist. Here's why: Stack Exchange is not about voting—it is about ["getting expert answers to your questions"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/). Voting helps the process, but voting isn't the key.

On the other hand, Facebook is about getting people to interact with each other through their tools—the more websites they are on, the better Facebook is doing. That's why they expend developer time to do this.

Stack Exchange has no such obligation to do this—why would they spend money (in development, testing, infrastructure, support) providing a free service when it is marginal to their core mission? And they probably wouldn't do this even if you paid them, because SE isn't a random development company—it's a company which has a mission, and this isn't part of it.

Maybe reddit or one of the other sites where voting on pages is the central focus has such a feature or would be willing to develop one. Maybe not. But even when Stack Exchange is about voting, it's only about voting on questions and answers. Not on random pages (if it were, then you'd be able to vote on badges and users and the like—but voting on random pages isn't important, so you can't).

Comment: You presented some brilliant points, thanks. Just as an add note, I want to say something on 'why they would provide a free service'. This is called shifted from website to web platform, definitely the more sites will depend upon their services (no matter how they are accessed), the market value of StackExchange will increase.