# Is it possible to have a look at technical details of SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I see SO, itself is very incredible in respect of a web application and software development. And all the children sites built on same lines in that respect.

I am really interested to have a look at few technical details about the back-end, what all programming languages are behind this? how the scalability is handled? the data model (may be a masked one, if that is a security risk) ? or any other tech things related to SO.

Also, the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) is a of a big interest to me, and would also be for others.

If this is possible, please let me know how can we get an insight of this?

Note: I have had a look at the [Stack exchange Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/)  site, I am looking for something in more detail.

Comment: related: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Thanks for the link. Was looking for such info.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/is-the-stack-overflow-source-code-available

Comment: There is a separate post about chat: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/what-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Stack Exchange source code is closed-source. I'm sure there are very good reasons which someone might be able to clarify, but I would think that some of the reasons would be

- So we don't have clone sites popping up
- Keeping all the experts in one place as opposed to having them spread out across different sites (one source of information)