# Would it be possible for SE to share the code they used to enable imgur uploading via PageDown?

Tags: discussion, code

I've been working with pagedown and am trying to customize the image modal that comes from Markdown.Editor.js to enable direct-to-imgur uploads.  I can handle that fine on a page of my own but I'm at a loss in terms of customizing Pagedown.

I'm not sure if this is the right channel to go through (and apologies if it isn't) - any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as of today, the policy is that it is closed from public view.

See - [Is the Stack Overflow source code available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/is-the-stack-overflow-source-code-available)

In a podcast they mentioned that [eventually they may go open-source.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14657/164243)

That said, it's fairly easy to reverse-engineer web-code, at least that's my gut-feeling. At  least to grab it, spruce it up, and call it your own(pay attention to legalities of course!).

Comment: Just started digging into it and it's not so bad.  line ~1160 in Markdown.Editor.js for anyone else looking to do this.

Comment: Individual components - such as PageDown - *are* shared though. I'm not sure that's worth doing for something like the image uploader, but if the dev team feels it's sufficiently decoupled from the rest of the code it could happen.