# Is Stack Overflow build out of an open sourced framework or can it be open sourced?

Tags: support, technology, open-source

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Will Open Sourcing Stack Overflow Destroy Our Business Model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/will-open-sourcing-stack-overflow-destroy-our-business-model)
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

Stack Overflow is a very modern discussion forum, very fast and effective.

Is it built upon an open sourced discussion forum framework?

If not, can the framework that Stack Overflow is built upon be open sourced?

Comment: See here for the discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/will-open-sourcing-stack-overflow-destroy-our-business-model

Comment: This has already been discussed many times and in great depth.  Check the podcasts and the transcripts of them, especially the early ones.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, in particular not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

> Is stackoverflow built upon an
> open-source discussion forum
> framework?

No, the software behind Stack Overflow is called [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/), and it is not open-source.

> If not, can the framework that
> StackOverflow built upon be open
> sourced?

[StackExchange is unlikely to be open-sourced anytime soon.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/will-open-sourcing-stack-overflow-destroy-our-business-model)  There is a similar knowledge-exchange platform called [Solace](http://opensource.plurk.com/Solace/) which is open-source.

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, the software behind Stack Overflow is *not* called StackExchange. "StackExchange" is the hosted version of the Stack Overflow software, available to the public as a paid service to build your own site. Stack Overflow was the original and built from the ground up using these components: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones), where several open and closed sourced clones written in different languages are discussed.