# Is this website open source?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, notifications, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Stack Overflow source code available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/is-the-stack-overflow-source-code-available)

I know that Stack Overflow has an API to let you know when you get a notification. I am wondering if this website and its features (like the ability to post questions) are open source and available for download. I was also wondering if the notification web code or the API code is available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Stack Overflow source code available?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/is-the-stack-overflow-source-code-available). Also see [Is Stack Overflow build out of an open sourced framework or can it be open sourced?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25512/is-stack-overflow-build-out-of-an-open-sourced-framework-or-can-it-be-open-sourc)